# How do I disassemble mips .o object files in ida elf 64bit

Tags: ida, disassembly, idapython, c, mips

So I’m trying to disassemble some object files in mips. I use IDA 7 on windows. These object files are loadable kernel modules. Mipself64 Is What ida auto sets to when they are dropped in. I’d like to get them back to c. Most likely they were compiled in mips4 aka mips pro as a 64 bit module. It shows decently in assembly. Probably not all correct, I’d like to use mips2c or epanos( mips2c but it works with ida used to disassemble electro paint) however I have no idea how to load libraries or use python with ida in windows.

I need python 3.6 I believe so the question is :

A. How do I load libraries and things with ida and use them to disassemble

B. What are some great ways to disassemble mips object files .o